# Set the selected language in an installer as the default language of the application

Tags: .net, localization, installation, wix, multilingual

First post Here. 
I am making a WPF application, and are currently using WIX to create installers in Visual Studio. This works great, but now the client wants to have multilanguage application and installation.

We have implemented localization in the application, so that is ok: the user can select language when the application is first started, and the selected language is remembered in user settings.

I also know that wix can be configured to create multiple installers, one for each supported language, or auto-detect the language of the OS and select that language as default.

But, we really want an installer that lets you select the installation language at the beginning of the installation process(so that we dont need to manage 20+ installers, and sometimes the OS language might be incorrect for autodetection). We have tested QSetup, and this works fine for creating multilanguage setup.

**So now to the essence of the question:** If using QSetup (or any other setup package), how would one go about to set the selected language in the installer as the selected language of the installed application? How can we detect the language selected in the installer and make a script to set that language as the default in the application settings file? Has anyone done this with any installation packages, and how did you do it?

I would like to see that the users dont have to select language twice: first for the installation, and then again the first time the application is started (the user can change language at any time later).

Any thoughts and hints on this would be greatly appreciated. We are not locked to any specific installer, though InstallShield professional is a bit to expensive for us at this moment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, my devil's advocate advice is "don't bother". There are many situations where a product is installed by an administrator using a language which is not the one of the final intended user. 
Second, the default language of the app should be the default user language of the system, not the one of whomever happened to install it.
Third, I hope the app has a way to change its language. Nobody wants to reinstall just to change the app's language. You used the term "default" so the app is probably mult-language.

After that, to be practical, if the install captures the language and can see its value, then just put in the registry for the current user and have the app pick it up from there. Whether the chosen language of the install is visible by the internals of the setup depends on the tool you use.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. Yeah, we are probably do what you said to begin with, don't bother, unless somebody can show me a way with QSetup or any other installation/setup package to make it work. I am not sure, and its hard to find in the QSetup documentation, if it is possible to detect selected language and then do actions based on that. And yes, the user can change language later.

Answer (score 0):

Update:
I solved this problem a long time ago, and I thought I should share it with the rest. I used PhilDW approach and put the selected language in the registry. Specifically, in QSetup, it is possible to add executable items to your installer, and it is possible to detect what language was selected. So in the execute dialog of the QSetup composer, I added an execute itemfor each language that was relevant for my installer.

So for french I added a new Execute item. I called it "French Selected", to be performed at "Setup End". The type is conditional. Under the "IF" section of the Composer GUI i set the condition to be "Selected Language is in", and then I chose "french".

Under the "THEN" section of the composer GUI I then selected :"Create Registry Value" under perform (a selection in the drop down). Then you can add three arguments to that action: The first is the registry string which in my case was "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE.........\SelectedLanguageDuringInstallation", then argument two was the key: installedLanguage, and then the last argument was the value: fr. These are selected by you. No drop down.

That's it. Now we have an action to be performed if the selected language was french. I had total of 10 supported languages in my installer, so I needed to create 10 different execute items. Pretty easy and powerful.

Then the first time I started the application after install I read the registry value and mapped that to the possible languages for the application.

Hope this helps someone.